# Curious gamma identity

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I found the following curious identity for the gamma function on Wikipedia for which I'd like to know some references (proof, history, etc).

The identity is as follows: $$\Gamma(t) = x^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{L_n^{(t)}(x)}{t+n}$$
Here $L_n^{(t)}(x)$ are the generalized Laguerre polynomials, and the expression seems to be valid for $\mathrm{Re}(t) < \frac12$. (That's all which is specified on Wiki).

EDIT: There are now two very helpful answer, but before accepting one of them I'd like to broaden the question a little bit further in asking for a representation theoretic interpretation of the gamma function identity.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your edit sufficiently changes your question that it is no longer the same question.  I recommend that you create a new question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generalized Laguerre polynomials have the generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\xi^n L_n^{(t)}(x)=(1-\xi)^{-t-1}e^{-\frac{\xi x}{1-\xi}}.$$
Multiplying this identity by $\xi^{t-1}$ and integrating w.r.t. $\xi$ from $0$ to $1$, one finds
\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{L_n^{(t)}(x)}{t+n}&=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\xi}{1-\xi}\right)^{t-1} e^{-\frac{\xi x}{1-\xi}}\frac{d\xi}{(1-\xi)^2}
=x^{-t}\int_0^{\infty}s^{t-1}e^{-s}ds=x^{-t}\Gamma(t),
\end{align}
where the second step is achieved by the change of variables $s=\frac{\xi x}{1-\xi}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! do you know of a representation theoretic interpretation of this description of the gamma function?

Comment: You are very welcome! and sorry, I cannot suggest any representation-theoretic interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

A reference:  Chaudhry, M.A. et al. [Asymptotics and closed form of a generalized incomplete gamma function](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/158/0158A.pdf).

Comment: I don't really support this rule , but someone on stackexchange once told me to not use links as an answer, but use link as a side to the answer, not as the main subject of the answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Joao:  At the time of this answer, there was an adequate demonstration, but zero references, as requested in the OP.

Comment: @EricTowers Ok thanks for clearing everthing up.